# Jquery animate. Display none css is not changing

Tags: jquery

In the first load of the page the image have to **display:none**. But the problem is, when I put display none, the animate function is not working and I already put a **.css({'display':'block'})** still not working.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img.fade").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": "1" }, 300);
            $(this).css({ 'display': 'block' });
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": "0" }, 300);
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    img.fade { display:none }
</style>
<img src="image.jpg" class="fade" />
```

If I remove the **display:none** style, it is working but when the page first loads, image is showing. I need to hide it in the first load then when hovering it will show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If something's hidden you can't hover over it, since it occupies no space in the page.  Instead set it's `opacity` to 0 initially.  Remove your CSS and you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.fade").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300);
    }).css({ opacity: 0 });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yEuMw/).  Or, remove `.css({ opacity: 0 });` and change your CSS to this:

```
img.fade { opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); }
```

[You can test that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yEuMw/1/).

Comment: Great answer. I think I need to learn more about jquery :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).css({'display':'block'}); == $(this).show();
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 300); == $(this).fadeOut(300);
```

etc

Change

```
$("img.fade").hover(
```

to

```
$("img.fade").hide().hover(
```

/E:

And remove style