# When resize, the div's width back to normal

Tags: jquery, html, css

### The problem

I have two columns: the first has responsive width, while the other has fixed width. I am using a plug-in who needs the width of the responsive column, then I made this function to calculate the width:

```
$(".container-content").css(
        "width",
        $(".site-container").outerWidth() - $(".sidebar").outerWidth()
    );
```

But when the page loads, the width isn't correct, I have to resize the window to get the width fixed.

### A bit of my code

**CSS**

```css
.site-container {
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: #b8b8b8 0 2px 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-body .container-content {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Let me know if you need something more.

### Update v1

I believe we are closer to the resolution of my problem. I have Isotope on my application to create a mosaic. When the page loads, Isotope is called. The structure of my mosaic is: `ul` > `li`. On CSS, `li` as defined as `display: none` to just display the mosaic's list after the page loader disappear.

When jQuery displays the li's content (with `fadeIn()`), I think he doesn't calculate properly the width (or not fully).

Follow the code:

```
// Isotope
jQuery("ul.products-list").isotope({
    itemSelector: "li",
    masonry: {
        gutterWidth: 15
    }
}, function () {
    $(this).parent().prepend("<div class=\"products-loader\"><p>Loading application</p></div>");
    $(".products-loader").delay(1000).fadeOut(300, function () {
        $("ul.products-list li").fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $(".products-loader").remove();
            $(".container-content").perfectScrollbar({
                wheelSpeed: 100
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

### Update v2 — I solved!

See my own answer.

Comment: Is your code wrapped in DOM ready or window load? I think we'll need more code to help you.

Comment: trigger resize via javascript

Comment: alert the values are getting proper or not and put the script top in header after css

Comment: Sorry about my late. @Karl-AndréGagnon, my code is wrapped in Window Load.

Comment: @JomyJoseph Values are only caught properly on resize.

Comment: @chiefGui you said that the width is fixed when you resize the window. `$(window).trigger('resize');` would help.

Comment: @claustrofob "What?" again. Not a fixed position. Anyway, I tried your suggestion — without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was switch from `display: none;` to `opacity: 0;`.

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009375/jquery-animate-display-none-css-is-not-changing).

Thank you to you all!

Answer (score 0):

A first thought:

You should make sure you run your jQuery code when the DOM is ready:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $(".content-container").css("width", $(".site-container").outerWidth() - $(".sidebar").outerWidth());
});
```

Or at least after the html it refers to (might not work in certain scenarios).

If the size of the components you wish to get the `outerWidth()` of depend on ex: images, that have to be loaded, then even the above is not enough. Then you have to put your code inside a `window.load` handler.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    /* your code*/
}
```

In short: `document.ready` is triggered when the DOM is ready as opposed to `window.load` which is triggered when everything on the page has loaded. For reference read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) or [here](http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/)

On a sidenote: Noticed the difference:

`.content-container [JS] <> .container-content [CSS]`
is that intended?

Comment: No, document ready doesn't mean that page (content) is loaded, just DOM is ready... window load is better option, in this case...

Comment: TY for noticing, extended answer

Comment: @Matyas I wrote the JS script when I created this topic — that's why one is different from another. So, if I put my code to run when DOM is ready, all internal components are invisible.